# Crawling through a form using Python Requests library

Tags: python, forms, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

I am new to web scraping and Python. I am trying to submit an email address through the following form:

http://post.oreilly.com/client/o/oreilly/forms/quicksignup.cgi

This is an exercise in Chapter 9 of "[Web Scraping with Python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920034391.do)", which involves signing up for O'Reilly newsletters.

Here is my code, which does not seem to be working:

```
import requests
parameters = {'email_addr': 'blahblah@blah.com', 'first_name': 'blah', 'last_name': 'blah'}
r= requests.post("http://post.oreilly.com/client/o/oreilly/forms/form/oreilly/signup4", data=parameters)
```

Comment: Can you post your code and indicate where in your code you are having issues?

Comment: @idjaw Please see the code above. Thanks!

Comment: how is it not working? what errors are you getting? what are you expecting your code to do?

Comment: @meter When you submit the form on the actual website, it sends a confirmation email. I am assuming the above code is not working because it does not produce the confirmation email. I am not getting any errors though.

Comment: serious question, how do you know you're not getting errors? are you saying this because Python is not throwing errors or the page response does not indicate an error.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes Response status code (r.status_code) is 200, which means the request is ok.